# Загрузка изображений на сервер и в БД - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Уважаемые программисты, при использовании кода неккоректно добавляются изображения в БД. Данный код загружает без проблем файлы на сервер, но при добавлении в БД:

1. Создает несколько пустых строк;
2. Записывает изображения в одной строке, в одной ячейке (image) через запятую.

Как сделать так, чтобы изображения записывались в своей отдельной строке в таблице, а не в кучу в одной ячейке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
$arr=array();

//ширина и высота в пикселях
$pic_weight = 3000;
$pic_height = 3000;

if ($_FILES)
{
  //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
  {
    //директория загрузки
    $uploaddir = "";
    //новое имя изображения
    $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.png';
    //путь к новому изображению
    $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

    //Проверка расширений загружаемых изображений
    if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/gif" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" ||
    $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
    {
      //черный список типов файлов
      $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
      foreach ($blacklist as $item)
      {
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k]))
        {
          echo "Нельзя загружать скрипты.";
          exit;
        }
      }

      //перемещаем файл из временного хранилища
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
      {
        //получаем размеры файла
        $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
        //проверяем размеры файла, если они нам подходят, то оставляем файл
        if ($size[0] < $pic_weight && $size[1] < $pic_height)
        {

          $arr[$apend] = "$uploaddir$apend";

          echo "<center><br>Файл ($uploadfile) загружен.</center>";
        }
        //если размеры файла нам не подходят, то удаляем файл unlink($uploadfile);
        else
        {
          echo "<center><br>Размер пикселей превышает допустимые нормы.</center>";
          unlink($uploadfile);
        }
      }
      else
        echo "<center><br>Файл не загружен, вернитесь и попробуйте еще раз.</center>";
    }
    else
      echo "<center><br>Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.</center>";
  }
}

$image = implode(",", $arr);
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO gallery (image) VALUES (?s)";
$db->query($sql1, $image);
```

Comment: Ваша конструкция `$image = implode(",", $arr);` сливает массив в строку через запятую. Эта строка и записывается в бд, что ж еще ожидать.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов а как правильно должно записываться? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо запомнить одно очень простое правило.
Для. Обработки. Массива. Всегда. Нужен. Цикл.

```
foreach($arr as $image) {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO gallery (image) VALUES (?s)", $image);
}
```

Это правило тебя никогда не подведет.

Comment: Вы лучший!!! Спасибо!